# InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "stmp" does not exist

Tags: symfony

This error starts to appear and i don't know why.

```
> in
> /sites/site1/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php
> line 678
>     at ContainerBuilder->getDefinition() in /sites/site1/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php
> line 703
>     at ContainerBuilder->findDefinition() in /sites/site1/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterPluginsPass.php
> line 31
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be `smtp`? Check your Swiftmailer configuration in `config.yml` or similar

Comment: yes, sorry. i just wrote stmp insted of smtp in parameters.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

i just wrote stmp insted of smtp in parameters.ini file and it happens. pretty strange because yesterday everything was working. maybe because of cache.